# Using "Comma" or "pipe" within JunitParams

Tags: java, junit, delimiter, junitparams

I'm trying to  use JunitParams in order to parametrized my tests. But my main problem is that the parameters are strings with special characters, tilde or pipe.

```
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.rules.ExpectedException;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import junitparams.JUnitParamsRunner;
import junitparams.Parameters;

@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)
public class TheClassTest {

    @Rule
    public ExpectedException exception = ExpectedException.none();

     @Test
     @Parameters({"AA~BBB"})
     public void shouldTestThemethod(String value) throws Exception {
        exception.expect(TheException.class);

        TheClass.theMethod(value);     
        // Throw an exception if value like "A|B" or "A~B",
        // ie if value contain a ~ or a |
    }
}
```

With tilde, I have no problem.
But with pipe, I have an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
```

The pipe, as the comma, is used as a separator for parameters.

Is there any way for me to set a different separator? 
Or is this a limitation of JunitParams?

Comment: You could work around using [this syntax](https://github.com/Pragmatists/JUnitParams/blob/master/src/test/java/junitparams/usage/Samples_of_Usage_Test.java#L34)

Comment: I would also try escaping the pipe with "\\", see [this sample](https://github.com/Pragmatists/JUnitParams/blob/master/src/test/java/junitparams/usage/Samples_of_Usage_Test.java#L114)

Comment: I tried this syntax, still does not work.

now I'm using Parameterized instead of JunitParams.

it's working, but the argument are for all the JunitClass (so i had to create a new class).

The "\\" works.
But because my parameters are hard to read (full of | and ~ and other special characters), I'd prefered not to add a lot of escaping character in my input sets.

But yes, it's working.

Answer (score 6):

You can indeed escape the pipe with double backslashes:

```
@Parameters("AA\\|BBB")
public void test(String value)
```

Comment: You can also escape the comma with this.

Answer (score 5):

I did not find an option to configure the separator chars, but these chars do not need to be escaped if you provide your data in an `Object[][]`.

Consider the following example:

```
public static Object[][] provideParameters() {
   return new Object[][] {
        new Object[] {"A,B|C"}
    };
}
```

Both `,` and `|` can be directly used, which significantly improves the readability of your tests.

Annotate your test with `@Parameters(method = "provideParameters")` to make use of this test factory. You can even move the factory to another class (e.g., `@Parameters(source = Other.class, method = "provideParameters")`).

Answer (score 1):

you can check [zohhak](https://github.com/piotrturski/zohhak). it's similar to junit params but gives you much more flexibility around parsing parameters. looks like it may help significantly in dealing with 'hard to read' parameters. examples from the docs:

```java
@TestWith(value="7 | 19, 23", separator="[\\|,]")
public void mixedSeparators(int i, int j, int k) {
    assertThat(i).isEqualTo(7);
    assertThat(j).isEqualTo(19);
    assertThat(k).isEqualTo(23);
}

@TestWith(value=" 7 = 7 > 5 => true", separator="=>")
public void multiCharSeparator(String string, boolean bool) {
    assertThat(string).isEqualTo("7 = 7 > 5");
    assertThat(bool).isTrue();
}
```